# Requiring unknown module “http” when using redux-dev-tools

Tags: react-native

This is my code snippet below :

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk    from 'redux-thunk';
import devTools from 'remote-redux-devtools';
import StockApp from '../reducers';

// create a store that has redux-thunk middleware enabled
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
  thunk
)(createStore);
alert("inside production");
export default function configureStore() {
  return createStoreWithMiddleware(StockApp);
}
```

Whenever i try to import remote-redux-devtools it gives me below screen

[image]

in case i try to remove `remote-redux-devtools` import statement everything goes well , please suggest or point out what can be cause when i specify redux dev tool in

Answer (score 0):

as the picture,you should ctrl+c end the server, and re-start, npm run start --reset-cache